# How to compose lenses that return Maybe (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

Suppose I have a lens like `at _` that needs some `Maybe a`:

```
import Data.Map as M
m = M.fromList [(1,(2,3))]
--set 2nd element
m ^. at 1 .~ Just (4,5) 
--gives fromList [(1,(4,5))]
m ^. at 1 .~ Nothing
--gives fromList ()
```

Now suppose I want to compose it with another lens. The fact that this lens returns some `Maybe a` prevents me from doing it directly.

```
m ^. at 1 . _2 .~ Just 4
--error
-- I want to get M.fromList [(1,(2,4))]
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `_Just` prism to set values in a Map conditional on whether the key exists. That's what prisms are for!

```
λ> let m = fromList [(1, (2, 3))]
λ> m & at 1 . _Just . _2 .~ 4
fromList [(1,(2,4))]
λ> m & at 100 . _Just . _2 .~ 4
fromList [(1,(2,3))]
```

Answer (score 3):

To set a value you can just write:

```
> m & ix 1 . _2 .~ 4
fromList [(1,(2,4))]
```

To get a value, you can do something similar:

```
> m ^? ix 1 . _2
Just 3
```